# spotfire data limiting on filtered values

Tags: expression, tibco, spotfire

I am trying to limit the visualization on only one month of the filtered values.

I want to my graph be on The Max([Date]) of my data.
I ve added [Date]=Max([Date]) on the Data limiting of my Viz but that's not working when I dont select the Max([Date]) of my Data.

For example:

My column :

```
Date

12/2015

11/2015

10/2015
```

My data liminting:

```
[Date] = Max([Date])
```

=> When All values are selected it display data for 12/2015

=> When Only 11/2015 and 10/2015 it does not display anything because I think it keeps the Max of all elements and not only on filtered elements

Any one can help ?

Comment: @ Ayyoub - Are you trying to filter dates using a property control? If you use max([Date]) in limit data by expression, it will always display data with max date.

Comment: Unfortunatly yes :(
I tried a Document property and with an IronPython script i save the value in a document property and I set my Column to my property value in data Limiting!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You'd like to enter a date in a property control, and this date should be used to limit your data in your visualization, showing only dates that are <= the date you enter, correct?

Comment: Ayyoub any response?

Comment: @scsimon I understood it as he was trying to limit the data to only show when the Date is equal to either a) the maximum date selected from a List Box (Multiple Select), which can be achieved with an on-change script changing the document property with a for loop or b) the maximum date which exists in his filtered down data set, which could be done with a cursor and a trigger (either via button or javascript), though this would probably be very slow.  Depending on the data set size, it may be more efficient to try to set up some related data table or additional Information Link.